# why jenkins SSH Agent asking for passprhase for ssh key without passphrase

Tags: jenkins

I created SSH key pair using ssh-keygen without passphrase. 
I am able to add this private key using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey_rsa` and it doesn't prompt me for a password.

But when I use this key to configure credential in Jenkins (SSH with username) and leave the passphrase field empty and use this credential in SSHAget of a job , the build fails with

```
Enter passphrase for
```

Why is that i am able to add private key without password but fails when same key is added in Jenkins credentials. 
I am using Jenkins Version 2.179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using advice from https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50181.
Add the trailing newline for private key. It helps me.